# Trying to hide specific div in jquery in php while loop

Tags: php, jquery, while-loop, show-hide

I have this form being outputted from a PHP while loop :

```
echo '<div id="postCont" class="postCont'.$pid.'" style="block;">
    <div id="clLink">
      <a id="clLink" href="'.$plink.'" target="_blank"" title="'.$ptitle.'">'.$ptitle.'</a>
    </div>
    <div id="clDate">Posted on '.$pdate.'</div>
    <div id="clDesc">'.$pdesc.'</div>

    <form method="post" class="ibadForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$pid.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenBad" value="yes">
        <input type="image" src="../img/bad.png" name="subBad" value="Bad" class="bad">
    </form>
</div>';
```

I am trying to remove the individual `.postCont` when the `ibadForm` is clicked with jquery.

```
$(".ibadForm").submit(function(e) {
     var url = "add_form.php"; 
     var id = <?php echo $pid?>;
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function(data)
         {
             $('.postCont' + id).hide();
         }
     });
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

It submits the form to `add_form.php` fine but doesn't hide the `postCont`. If I remove the id from the class then it hides all post Cont's. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `closest()` to get the parent `div` then hide it using `hide()` method like :

```
$(".ibadForm").submit(function(e) {
  var url = "add_form.php"; 
  var id = <?php echo $pid?>;
  var _this = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    {
      _this.closest('.postCont').hide();
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**NOTE :** You should store the `$(this)` object that refer to the clicked `form` in some variable (`_this` in my example) then use it inside the success callback since `$(this)` inside callback doesn't refer no more to the form, e.g :

```
_this.closest('.postCont').hide();
```

Hope this helps.